# Running Java program on multiple servers

Tags: java, ssh, server

I wrote a Java program to populate a Database. Currently I run the program on the server and populate the database on the server.

Now I need to run the program locally, and populate the databases in multiple servers. (It is the same database on all servers).

How would I approach this, and does java allow me to connect to a server to run the code then disconnect then repeat with another server?

For example is there a way to connect via via ssh, then disconnect and connect to another server via ssh and repeat the run of the program?

Comment: Nope. ssh only i guess. Unless u wrote client server app

Comment: Why the same database on multiple servers?  Does each client have its own?  No reason to ever combine them?  Duplication is usually a bad practice.

Comment: Challenging this approach ... why not have the servers replicate/sync amongst each other? A distributed database has other benefits other than just being a backup. Also the connect/disconnect situation does not seem ideal ... I would suggest at least a multi-tier solution, web services etc ...

Comment: Also why do you need to connect over ssh, can you not connect to the database remotely but directly using jdbc?

Comment: What kind of database? How do you connect to it (locally)? It depends on the database and the type of connection if you can connect to a remote one.

Comment: @cello I connect using JDBC, I am wondering how to connect to the servers, connecting to the databases is not an issue.

Comment: @YoYo how do I do that?

Comment: "You" don't have to connect to the server (i.e. by ssh), the database driver ("JDBC") will do it for you given you provided the correct IP address and the port is reachable from your machine.

Comment: @duffymo The servers each serve different customers

Comment: Your situation is much different from what I thought it was. I would actually reverse the whole situation and have the customers servers “call back” your service to get whatever data they need. Your service would run in a server by itself, and not just ‘local’.  Google “java ee 7 jax-rs”.

Comment: A server per customer?  That can't scale unless you plan to have as few customers as possible in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Given you connect to the database using JDCB, you likely use a connection string comparable to this one:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
```

Probably you don't specify `localhost` or the port number, in which case your connection string would look like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://dbname
```

In such a case, the default host (being `localist`) and default port would be used.

To connect to a database on a different server, you would specify the IP address or the server's host name in the connection string:

```
jdbc:mysql://123.123.123.123:3306/dbname
jdbc:mysql://my-db-server.com:3306/dbname
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create multiple instances of java.sql.Connection, one for each database you want to connect to. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html